# NOT NULL constraint failed error when using createview in django

Tags: python, django, model, relation

I am trying to create a new entry in my model using createview. the model Venue is in a onetone relation with Adress model and I cannot get it to upate that model. I have tried to use a custom form but I always get the following error:

```
IntegrityError at /evcreate/

NOT NULL constraint failed: kammem_person.padress_id
```

form.py:

```
class AdressForm(ModelForm):

    street=CharField(max_length=100)
    snumb=CharField(max_length=15)
    town=CharField(max_length=100)
    postn=CharField(max_length=5,validators=[postnvali])
    
    class Meta:
        model=Person
        exclude=['padress']
```

view:

```
class EvCreate(CreateView):

    form_class=AdressForm
    template_name='kammem/create.html'
    success_url=reverse_lazy('event')

    def form_valid(self,form):
        
        street=form.cleaned_data['street']
        snumb=form.cleaned_data['snumb']
        town=form.cleaned_data['street']
        postn=form.cleaned_data['postn']
        form.vadress=Adress.objects.create(street=street,snumb=snumb,town=town,postn=postn)

        return super().form_valid(form)
```

models.py

```
class Person(Model):

    fname=CharField(default="missing",max_length=100)
    lname=CharField(default="missing",max_length=100)
    mobil=PhoneField(default='9999999999')
    mail=EmailField(default='contact@gmail.com')
    padress=OneToOneField(Adress,on_delete=CASCADE,primary_key=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.fname

    class Meta:
        ordering=('fname','lname')

class Venue(Model):

    vname=CharField(default="",max_length=100)
    vamil=EmailField(default='contact@gmail.com')
    vpage=CharField(default='homepage',max_length=100)
    vadress=OneToOneField(Adress,on_delete=CASCADE,,primary_key=True)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return 'Venue: ' + self.vname
```

url.py

```
   path('evcreate/',EvCreate.as_view(),name='evcreate'),
```

I have really searched for an answer but with no succes. Any clues?

Comment: `form.vadress=` did you mean to write `form.instance.padress=` (in your `form_valid` method of class `EvCreate`)? Also the name AddressForm is very misleading considering it is a form to make a Person instance

Comment: the name is misleading, true. yes, I mean form.instance.padress=

Answer (score 0):

You are missing **padress** which you have set as Primary Key.

In AdressForm you have excluded **padress** and Django creates view automatically creates the object if the form is valid.

try something like this

```
def form_valid(self,form):
    form.padress = # Adress object
    form.save()
    # rest
```